# Plotting Logarithmic Limit in Chart

Tags: excel

I have logarithmic trendline in Excel.
My question is - how can I find and plot a limit on the same graph for the logarithmic trendline? (straight line parallel to X axis)

Comment: Technically speaking, logarithmic functions have no upper limit, although for restricted datasets they may appear to have an upper limit because it grows so slowly. So I'm not sure how to answer your question on how to find the upper limit. But there are many tutorials on how to add horizontal lines to charts in Excel, [such as this one](https://peltiertech.com/add-horizontal-line-to-excel-chart/).

Comment: I need to find a model which looks something like algorithmic function and has a limit. Do you know what I could use?

Comment: What? What is an "algorithmic function"? Also "model" is a very general term so I have no idea what you're asking when you say you need to find a model. Please reword your question, probably with sample data, telling us specifically what you want to accomplish.